# How to get a State Visitor Permit for a rented self-drive car in India?

Tags: india, car-rentals, permits, bangalore, tamil-nadu

I am planning to travel from Bangalore, Karnataka to Hogenakkal, Tamil Nadu. I am going to book a self-drive car with Karnataka Registration.

A permit is necessary to enter the Tamil Nadu State. Where should I obtain the permit while travelling?

I have heard that the permit can be obtained from RTO Check post at the state border. I need information related to ithis (location, fee, validity, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all Rent a cab services,

If entering from Karnataka to TamilNadu via Hosur, there is RTO check post where temporary permits are provided for one week,

4+1 = ₹150 + handling charges ~₹100

Comment: What's the logic behind requiring a permit for rental cars?..

Comment: @JonathanReez Vehicle registration and taxation is specific to the state in India, and commercial vehicles, including rental cars, require permits to cross state lines. This is actually [identical to the system](https://www.irponline.org/page/TripPermits) in the United States and Canada, just that every national rental company has [taken care of it for you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Registration_Plan).

Comment: @user71659 in the US this only applies to buses and trucks, not to rental cars

Comment: @JonathanReez Negative. [See page 11](https://www.michigan.gov/documents/2002IRPmanual_17888_7.pdf). Check the registration certificate next time you're in a US rental car, it will be apportioned. Otherwise rental car fleets with out-of-state plates would be regularly breaking the law.

Comment: @user71659 nope, see page 4 for clarification of scope: "The International Registration Plan (IRP) is a program for licensing commercial vehicles (**trucks, trailers,
and buses**) in interstate operations among member jurisdictions (states or provinces)"

Comment: @JonathanReez Read page 11. It details _exactly how to calculate registration fees_ for rental passenger vehicles based on percentage of revenue. It's not true IRP, because it's not miles, but it still is an **apportioned registration**. The rental company has taken care of paying the appropriate taxes for you in the state the vehicle operates in, independent of the license plate state.

Comment: @user71659 again, please check page 4 to see that this doesn't in any way apply to regular passenger vehicles. It does apply if you rent a bus, which is indeed covered on page 11.

Comment: @JonathanReez Since you refuse to believe a rental car is a "rental passenger vehicle" I present [State 2. Page 9.](http://www.dot.state.wy.us/files/live/sites/wydot/files/shared/Motor%20Vehicle%20Services/IRP_IFTA/2016%20IRP%20MANUAL.pdf) "IRP specifically provides for the registration of various types of rental fleets... **Rental Passenger Cars**", specifying the exact same taxation method.  I've rented enough cars in the US to see the apportioned registration in the glovebox.

Comment: @user71659 if so, how on earth would the rental company know where you've driven their cars and for how long? Buses and trucks keep detailed records, but if I spend a month down in California the rental company in Washington would have no idea whatsoever, unless they've installed a GPS tracker.

Comment: @JonathanReez For rental trucks they make a best-effort calculation based on the [route between where you picked it up and returned it](https://www.bostonglobe.com/metro/regionals/north/2014/08/02/who-taught-you-drive-apportioned-license-plates/r8iQCPr1oTHmldnBEYC2SJ/story.html). For rental cars, if you read the linked documents, its based on the state where the revenue accrues. "Divide the _gross revenue received... from passenger car rental transactions occurring in Wyoming_ by the total gross revenue" So the state which charged the sales tax.

Comment: @user71659 so what's the point of sharing the revenue from rental cars if all of it is going to the state where the car is registered? That's essentially an extra tax on rentals, not a way to share taxes between states.

Comment: @JonathanReez You misunderstand. If a rental car company gets 25% of its revenue from State A, that is they were rented out in State A, then **any** 25% of its cars have to be registered in State A with consequent allocation of tax dollars. However, it does not matter what state an individual car is registered in to operate. A single car could operate its entire life in State A with State B registration, as long as the registrations were reconciled on a fleetwide basis. Far better than EU requirements of transferring registrations between countries.

Comment: @user71659 but then India's law is on a whole different level as it's concerned with where the rental car *drives*, rather than where it's registered or rented. To me that's a bizzare regulation.

Comment: @JonathanReez And that _is_ the system in the United States for companies that do not participate in these reconciliation schemes. I linked to a page showing "trip permits" for trucks. For cars, you have to re-register the car within 30 days of entering the state, with fees payable from the date you entered. (Most states charge you for the whole year at once, and a number won't refund when you leave). Even worse, EU [restricts registration](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g188045-i336-k9485209-Illegal_to_drive_Swiss_hire_car_in_the_EU-Switzerland.html) based on the driver's residency.

Comment: @user71659 but if I rent a car in Poland nobody would stop me from entering Germany or demand that fees are paid. Likewise renting a car in Washington does not attract any fees when crossing to Oregon or provide Oregon with any tax revenue even if you spend a whole month there. This is why the Indian system is bizarre. And I do agree that the Swiss-EU car rental situation is absurd :)

Comment: @user71659 I've created a question based on your link: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/118973/can-i-drive-a-swiss-registered-rental-car-in-the-eu-as-an-eu-resident

Comment: @JonathanReez That is true for cars. Trucks often have inspections (physical or [electronic](https://www.truckinginfo.com/155904/bypassing-tolls-and-weigh-stations-with-technology)) at state lines where they check paperwork. However, it doesn't mean it's not illegal. A traffic stop, accident, [parking ticket](https://wtop.com/ticketbuster/2014/08/ticketbuster-md-and-va-residents-get-tickets-in-dc-during-overnight-hours/), or if you're a big company, a tax audit, will discover improper registration and attract penalties.

Comment: @user71659 OK, I take my words back after reading the DC parking post. I've created a question based on it on Politics.SE: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/32411/why-does-each-us-state-handle-car-registrations-and-driver-licensing-separately

Answer (score 0):

I have driven several times from Bangalore to Goa, Kerala, Tamil Nadu, and Pondicherry. I never needed a permit to enter any of these states. My Uttar Pradesh license and Karnataka registration worked even when it was checked at border check posts.

Having said that, I guess the rules are different if you book a self-drive rental vehicle. In which case, it should be the responsibility of the company renting out the car to you to provide the necessary permits, although I believe most of those cars will have national permits anyway. I know ost taxis do.

Comment: For Personal vehicle you don't require permit. If u are renting a self drive rental car, You are supposed to obtain on your own for the car companies like Zoom Car, Carzonrent, ecorentacar.